# (n-1)st/th: n minus oneth or first?

Tags: pronunciation, writing, ordinal-numbers

1. Should I write (n-1)<sup>th</sup> or (n-1)<sup>st</sup>
2. Relatedly, is it "n minus oneth" or "n minus first".

Thanks!